# What's a good word/phrase for "something that may not lead to anything concrete"

Tags: phrases, email

I was passing a lead to a potential project to my manager via email. Because he's super busy, I wanted to say something like the following at the end of the email.

"I hope this doesn't add _______ to your busy schedule."

where ______ = something that takes time to follow up, but may not lead to anything concrete

What's a good word/phrase for that? Or is there a better way to end the email politely?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say [**busywork**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/busywork):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : work that usually appears productive or of intrinsic value but actually only keeps one occupied

The repetition of *busy* actually works well in your example sentence if you add another word:

> I hope this doesn't add busywork to your *already* busy schedule.